# Ferns have not survived winter, what might be the case?

Tags: diagnosis, perennials, ferns, winter

We are renting a flat with a nice garden in Leeds UK. It has a nice garden in the back yard and when we moved in in July 2014 there were 4 healthy ferns pleasing my eye.

Now, with winter having passed, they all seem to be dead and I do not know when exactly that happen.

I tried to search google for clues about why this might happen, but could not find anything.

Could anyone tell me if this is a normal thing or not (are ferns supposed to not survive English winter?). Could it be a disease?

I have no idea as to what kind of ferns they are, but maybe this picture would clarify this:

[image: one of the ferns]

Comment: They probably went dormant for the winter, and will regrow when it gets warmer out. This is common in ferns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll guess that the ferns have gone dormant for the winter, as many do, and that they will return when the weather warms up. This is normal, and nothing to worry about.